# Alternatives to McAfee epolicy orchestrator (ePO)

Tags: untagged

Over the past few weeks I have been losing time into fixing McAfee ePO Agent and Server issues, it's becoming a black hole for my productivity. I don't want to discuss those issues in this question.

What I want to know if anyone can share their experiences and/or recommendations for a small to medium office environment anti-virus solution. This would include a suite for Workstation/Server protection, Exchange Group Shield lookalike, Remote Admin management console etc...

So basically what ePO does for us at the moment.

We are a small sized business of < 20 people but need a solution that allows some scalability and some decent automation/remote admin control. Our environment is Windows and consists of everything from Win 2000 and up.

Alternate places like Kapersky, F-Secure, AVG etc etc... What options do they have, what are your experiences with them or what could you recommend me looking at.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past few years we have been using  [**Kaspersky® Open Space Security™**](http://www.kaspersky.com/open_space_security) ;) with great success in companies ranging from 5 users to companies as large as 300 users. We are Protecting Exchange, File and Citrixservices aswell as clients (mostly xp). Every Product can be administrated throug the Kaspersky Admin Console. It´s easy to use.

We found out though that it needs loads of ram (768MB and up) - yes there were times when that was considered an exessive amount. And if you configure it too strict, you can take a performance hit.

Comment: Since your the only one who posted ill give it to you =)